# Htaccess - redirect every request to a single page. Side effects?

Tags: php, performance, .htaccess

I am creating my own mvc framework to use in little projects and by default, I am rewriting the url so that every single request goes to index.php. Index.php is only 4-5 lines, which calls the application class and then, the application class calls the corresponding controller and so on.

Basically, this is my htaccess file and index.php:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

index.php:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$app = new Application();
?>
```

What I'd like to learn is whether this method has or could have any negative effects in the future in terms of speed and bandwidth. I appreciate your answers and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class is there just to wrap you bootstrap stage, then it is pointless. simply have a plain file, which initializes application, load configuration and does all the wiring.

You could also want the `index.php` file to only contain one line: something that includes file outside `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. This way, if something goes *tits-up* with PHP extension, you won't show everyone your DB password and other sensitive details about your code.

As for your current *.htaccess* setup - no , it will not cause any additional bandwidth usage, but you might think about utilizing browser's cache for image and other assets.

Answer (score 1):

Why redirect and not url rewrite?

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

as for example, this is used by a lot of applications/websites, and you have absolute control of the URL accessed.

And yes, redirecting is another call to the server.